# how to add rows in dynamically in generated columns horizontly

Tags: c#, asp.net

Ihave to add rows in:

```
 dtbl = new DataTable();
 dtbl.Columns.Add("Ad.No", typeof(String)); alignment[0] = 'C'; width[1] = 40;
 dtbl.Columns.Add("AdmissionDate", typeof(String)); alignment[1] = 'C'; width[2] = 50;
 dtbl.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(String)); alignment[2] = 'L'; width[3] = 100;
 dtbl.Columns.Add("Class", typeof(String)); alignment[3] = 'C'; width[5] = 40;
 for (int i = model.FromYear; i <= model.ToYear; i++)
 {
   for (int j = model.FromMonth; j <= model.ToMonth; j++)
   {
     for (int k = model.FromDay; k <= model.ToDay; k++)
     {
       dtbl.Columns.Add(Common.CommonUtility.GetShortMonthName(j)+" "+k, typeof(String)); alignment[4] = 'C'; width[5] = 40;
     }
   }

   for (int i = model.FromYear; i <= model.ToYear; i++)
   {
     for (int j = model.FromMonth; j <= model.ToMonth; j++)
     {
       for (int k = model.FromDay; k <= model.ToDay; k++)
       {
         //  dtbl.Rows.Add(dt[j]=std.value);
         //   foreach (var r in std.value){

         dtbl.Rows.Add(dt["Ad.No"] = std.AdmissionNo, dt["AdmissionDate"] = Convert.ToDateTime(std.date.ToString()).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), dt["Class"] = std.Class, dt["Name"] = std.StudentName,dt[j]=std.value);
       }
     }
```

I have to add rows in columns cell like  p A p A

Comment: What type of data is `std`? Is it data for one row of the table?

Comment: ya iam fetching the record from std

Comment: That last statement makes no sense. Please correct it. (You appear to be modifying a `DataRow` instance while also adding it to a `DataTable`, but there is no sign that you've created a new `DataRow` instance.)

Answer (score 1):

When creating the columns, the column name could contain also the year to be unique:

```
private GetColumnName(int year, int month, int day)
{
  return year.ToString() + " " + Common.CommonUtility.GetShortMonthName(month) + " " + day;
}
```

If `std` contains the value for one date, it would help if the `std` record provided also this date (or three properties year, month, day).

Then a list of `std` loaded from DB could be grouped by row identifier (is it the Ad.No?) and each group processed to fill one row:

```
var stdList = ... select from DB;

var stdGroups = stdList.GroupBy(x => x.AdmissionNo);

foreach(var group in stdGroups)
{
  var stds = group.ToList();

  var row = dtbl.NewRow(); // a new row of untyped data table
  row["Ad.No"] = stds.First().AdmissionNo;
  // ...set also the other properties

  for (int i = model.FromYear; i <= model.ToYear; i++)
  {
    for (int j = model.FromMonth; j <= model.ToMonth; j++)
    {
      for (int k = model.FromDay; k <= model.ToDay; k++)
      {
        var std = stds.Single(x => x.Year == i && x.Month == j && x.Day == k);
        row[GetColumnName(i,j,k)] = std.value;

       }
     }
  }

  dtbl.Rows.Add(row);
}
```